# Using Reactive cocoa to observe UITouches?

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

Im fairly new to reactive cocoa and im trying to include elements of FRP in the game i am trying to build. From my search online the resources and the documentation for Reactive cocoa seems very limited and most of the tutorials use the same examples!

What i want to do is, to have a RACSignal that gives a stream of values for the current touch on the view (assume no multi touch for simplicity). And then use subscribeNext to perform my actions as and when the UITouch Object gets mutated. Im having trouble setting up the RAC signal itself!

Currently im doing the following (which im not sure is the right way!)

```
  @interface MyView:UIView{

      UITouch *currentTouch;
      RACSignal *touchSignal;
  }
  @property(nonatomic , assign)UITouch *currentTouch;



  @implementation MyView
  @synthesize currentTouch;

  -(id)init{
     if(self = [super init]){

    }
    return self;
  }

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   NSArray *touchArray = [touches allObjects]; 
   for(UITouch *touch in toucheArray){   
       currentTouch = touch;  
       if(!touchSignal){
           touchSignal = [RACObserve(self , currentTouch) distinctUntilChanged];
       }

    }

}
```

But everytime i the RACSignal tries to initialize the game crashes and i get the following:

```
 [MyView rac_valuesForKeyPath:observer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2084cf90
```

What am i doing wrong? What is the correct way to set up a RACSignal? Also, how can i use the touchSignal in a different object (maybe the MyView Model) and use subscribe next to carry out operations in a block?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it, using `-rac_signalForSelector:`. This is more declarative, less imperative (which is where I think your bugs are coming from).

```
RACSignal *touchSignal = [[[self
    rac_signalForSelector:@selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:)]
    reduceEach:^(NSSet *touches, UIEvent *event) {
        return [touches anyObject];
    }]
    distinctUntilChanged]
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try. And Im assuming i can subscribe (using [[MyViewInstance touchSignal] subscribeNext:....]) to my touchSignal in another object as long as its a public property of MyView?

Comment: Tried it. Have the same problem! Im getting this 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyView rac_signalForSelector:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20874d80'.

What am i missing?

Comment: Are you sure ReactiveCocoa is linked properly into your app? You'll need the linker flag `-ObjC`, in "Other Linker Flags". The full steps are here: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#importing-reactivecocoa

Comment: The crash happens because the touchesBegan method does not exist. If you add an empty implementation of touchesBegan to your class it will fix it. Probably not the best solution though.

Comment: @Dave Lee, If I use -ObjC flag then it works, but I don't want to use this flag because it affecting to my other libraries which I have used. So is there any way other than -ObjC or could you please tell me what is dependency of this flag to run ReactiveCocoa signals?

Comment: @SunilTarge I believe the -ObjC flag is needed when there are source files that contain only Objective-C class categories. In ReactiveCocoa there are many such category-only files to provide reactive interfaces to non-reactive classes. For example: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/a135a1f755c5e4435634a5432a0b622eb323f5d7/ReactiveCocoa/Objective-C/NSURLConnection%2BRACSupport.m